# How can I add the link to the image or ttitle?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add the link on the image or title. when I click on the image/text it should take me to another page index.html.

How can I do that?

```
 const apiUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie
sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=04c35731a5ee918f014970082a0088b1&page=1;
const IMGPATH = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280";

const SEARCHAPI = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie? 
&api_key=04c35731a5ee918f014970082a0088b1&query=";

const main = document.getElementById("main");
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const search = document.getElementById("search");

showMovies(apiUrl);
function showMovies(url){
    fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
    .then(function(data){
    console.log(data.results);
    data.results.forEach(element => {
        const el = document.createElement('div');
        const image = document.createElement('img');
        const text = document.createElement('h2');

        text.innerHTML = `${element.title}`;
        image.src = IMGPATH + element.poster_path;
        el.appendChild(image);
        el.appendChild(text);
        main.appendChild(el);
    }); 
});
}


form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    main.innerHTML = '';
     
    const searchTerm = search.value;

    if (searchTerm) {
        showMovies(SEARCHAPI + searchTerm);
        search.value = "";
    }
});
```

Comment: your code doesn't run.  Provide a working snippet.  You need to use an anchor tag and place the image inside the tag

Comment: thats my snippet. do i need to post html code to?

Comment: 1) post it as an actual snippet.  2) fix the problem with the snippet (it doesn't run)(yes, add the html too)

Comment: `const el = document.createElement('a')` assign it the URL  and put the image inside it

Comment: how can I add html code here? sorry I am not used to this site

Comment: const el = document.createElement('a') I tried that still not working

Comment: to add a code snippet with a run button you click on the icon that to the right of the image icon, it looks like a document or page with `<>` on it

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your code, the tick was to add a  element instead of  with the desired href

```
    const apiUrl =
  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/moviesort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=04c35731a5ee918f014970082a0088b1&page=1";
const IMGPATH = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280";

const SEARCHAPI =
  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie? &api_key=04c35731a5ee918f014970082a0088b1&query=";

const main = document.getElementById("main");
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const search = document.getElementById("search");

showMovies(apiUrl);
function showMovies(url) {
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log(data.results);
      data.results.forEach((element) => {
        el = document.createElement("a");
        el.href = "https://example.com"
        const image = document.createElement("img");
        const text = document.createElement("h2");

        text.innerHTML = `${element.title}`;
        image.src = IMGPATH + element.poster_path;
        el.appendChild(image);
        el.appendChild(text);
        main.appendChild(el);
      });
    });
}

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  main.innerHTML = "";

  const searchTerm = search.value;

  if (searchTerm) {
    showMovies(SEARCHAPI + searchTerm);
    search.value = "";
  }
});
```